# Regular expression to index observations that match condition

Tags: r, regex, indexing, rlang

I have a table, namely `USstorms` with 902297 observations. Where `table(USstorms$CROPDMGEXP)` returns

```
            ?      0      2      B      k      K      m      M 
618413      7     19      1      9     21 281832      1   1994
```

I know that I can index to the observation where `USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="m"` by the code `USstorms[USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="m",]`.

How to index to all observation with both "m" and "M" values in them?
I tried `USstorms[USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="[Mm]",]` but it doesn't work.

However, this `USstorms[grep("[Mm]",USstorms$CROPDMGEXP),]` works well to return all observations that contain "m" and "M". For example `count(USstorms[grep("[Mm]",USstorms$CROPDMGEXP),])` returns `1995`

Why the regular expression in `USstorms[USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="[Mm]",]` does not work?

I tried
`count(USstorms[USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="[Mm]",])` and expect the return `1995` but it returns `0` instead.

Comment: This `USstorms[USstorms$CROPDMGEXP=="[Mm]",]` does not work, because this filters the variable `USstorms$CROPDMGEXP` for a character which is exactly `"[Mm]"`. 
But this `USstorms[grep("[Mm]",USstorms$CROPDMGEXP),]` works, because you are using a `grep` with a regular expression by defining a group which contains either `M` or `m` .
The syntax is `grep(pattern, x, ...)` . The pattern is `"[Mm]"` and x is the variable `USstorms$CROPDMGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from MarBlo's comment, here's some code to help explain it:

```
df <- tibble(
    names = c("Mm", "Mark", "mark","[Mm]")
)

# even though this looks like a regex, it's not; it's literally looking for the string "[Mm]"
df$names == "[Mm]" # [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# this searches for "M" and/or "m" in the string
grepl("[Mm]", df$names) # [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

# this searches for "M" and "m" in the string
grepl("M", df$names) & grepl("m", df$names) # [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```